# oracle trigger ORA-04084: 이 트리거 유형에 트리거 NEW 값을 변경할 수 없습니다

Tags: oracle, triggers

I do not speak English well. Sorry.

If I define this trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER abcdef 
  after UPDATE of ORGNZT_ID ON COMTNEMPLYRINFO_1 
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      update COMTNEMPLYRINFO_1 set ETC_1 = :old.OFFM_TELNO , ETC_2 = '10' where UNIQ_ID = :old.UNIQ_ID;
  END;
```

it compiles. But,

```
update COMTNEMPLYRINFO_1  set ORGNZT_ID ='ABC' where UNIQ_ID = 'UNIQ_001'
```

> ```
> ORA-06512: 
> ORA-04088: 트리거 'EGOV.ABCDEF'의 수행시 오류
> ```

---

And the trigger I want is:

```
create or replace TRIGGER abcdef 
after UPDATE of ORGNZT_ID ON COMTNEMPLYRINFO_1 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.ORGNZT_ID <> :OLD.ORGNZT_ID) THEN
        :NEW.ETC_1 := :OLD.OFFM_TELNO;
        :NEW.ETC_2 := '10';
    END IF;
END;
```

But I am getting an error:

> ```
> ORA-04084: 이 트리거 유형에 트리거 NEW 값을 변경할 수 없습니다
> 04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
> *Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
>           insert or update triggers.
> *Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.
> ```

How to solve this?

Comment: If you're using a trigger to update the values of columns in the same table, then you want to use a `BEFORE` trigger instead of an `AFTER` trigger. `AFTER` triggers are generally used for updating *other* tables.

Comment: In order to get error messages in English you can run this command: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'english';` It makes us easier to help you.

Comment: Why do you put number `10` as string?

Comment: String 10 test data thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:NEW` and `:OLD` values are available only in `BEFORE UPDATE`, so your trigger must be like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER abcdef 
BEFORE UPDATE of ORGNZT_ID ON COMTNEMPLYRINFO_1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.ORGNZT_ID <> :OLD.ORGNZT_ID) THEN
        :NEW.ETC_1 := :OLD.OFFM_TELNO;
        :NEW.ETC_2 := '10';
    END IF;
END;
```

`REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` is redundant, you can skip it if you like.